# Ruby validation based off of different field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am new to rails validation.

I have two fields:

```
field :feed_entitlements, :type => Array
...
field :alert_news, :type => Boolean, :default => false
```

I want to put a validation on "alert_news" that requires a count > 0 in "feed_entitlements".  Is this possible using a rails validation?  It seems like all examples of validations that I can find are simple "can't be blank" type problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your model this code

```
def validate
   errors.add_to_base "count should be more then 0" if feed_entitlements.count < 0
end
```